# Designing dual tracking regulator low noise PSU

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, ldo, tracking, dual-supply

I want to design a power supply with the following constraints

- Inputs 19 V - 0 - 19 V secondary & 9.5 V secondary - A transformer I have
  ready for the project, primary 230V

. Output +15 & -15 V, +5 V.

- Imax 350 mA on all rails.
- Parameters are low noise, low ripple.

I do not want to use a SMPS and rip out all the existing PSU for this project purely because I am working within existing constraints and I don't have any experience with SMPS design, especially with trying to make something with low noise and ripple. Furthermore as this is an old piece of equipment I want to hope the power supply will last more than the few years than a SMPS will typically last for.

I was looking at LM317 & LM337 for this, however, in the interests of using modern ICs I opted for LT3090 and LT3065 LDOs. I liked the look of this circuit: https://community.element14.com/technologies/open-source-hardware/b/blog/posts/building-a-linear-power-supply-module
However, I need the power rails to track and was thinking of adding an op amp to do this. However, I am wondering what reference voltage I should use and the most efficient way to derive it. Also the pin descriptions are different on the two ICs so I am assuming they are not complementary pairs, the specs are slightly different for Vmax so I am wondering whether I ought to change the part from what is in the schematic.

[image: LDO design]

As these parts are MSOP package, I was wondering about heat sinking requirements and how effectively this can be achieved. If we assume the supply is drawing Imax, then the supply is losing 25% as heat theoretically. I can fasten a piece of steel to the existing heat sink and use mica paper and heatsink compound to cool the chips.

The original supply was based on TA7179P in the early 80s, these are very very rare/unavailable but miraculously they are on AliExpress for 1.99. Rather than run the gauntlet with fake chips I want to redesign a similar power supply with better noise rejection. I also want to use the same design for a bench power supply and kill two birds with one stone. The layout would be the same except I would use a switch for a pot to adjust the voltage if needed and a fixed 15 V which is what I intend to use it for, for the most part.

So basically what I want to know before I start on the schematic is how do I select a reference voltage, the most efficient way to derive it, and how I would implement the tracking in this instance. Also could the choice of LDO be better for this application, are there alternative implementations that are achievable that can be more power efficient without introducing a whole heap of complications? My experience with power supplies is limited to 78XX and 79XX designs, I tend towards microcontrollers so this is not an area I have a lot of experience in but I am ready to take a step forward to something more advanced!

Cheers

Comment: What does the word primary mean here --> *Inputs 19 V - 0 - 19 V primary & 9.5 V primary*?

Comment: My bad, I apologise this was meant as the secondary side of the transformer, updated post

Comment: OK, so a 19-0-19 secondary produces a DC voltage of +26 and -26 volts when bridge rectified. Is that what you are saying i.e. are you saying that the 19-0-19 secondary are the RMS AC voltages from the centre-tapped secondary of the transformer?

Comment: 38V is what was specified, I just measured the AC voltage and its actually 36.4V

Comment: I can't say I understand what voltages are powering your intended circuit. This needs to be resolved.

Comment: 19+19 = 38V, I measured 36.4V so its actually -18.2  0 18.2 measuring from the centre tap. This gives a voltage of -21.5 & 21.5V DC after the rectifier according to the schematic, however, the rectifier is very old: 1B414B so maybe forward voltage drop is higher on these old parts.

Comment: So, please state unambiguously what the DC input to the circuit is. State the limits too and the ripple voltages; all these things are needed for a successful design.

Comment: Those regulators have built in references. Any particular reason you feel the need for a different one?

Comment: +25.15 & -25.15 volts using the rectifier I have here will be the DC input voltages. The spec is 350mA for the combined +15 & -15V outputs and 350mA for the 5V line. I'm not sure what ripple voltage I need to consider

Comment: I don't feel the need to use a different reference voltage as such, I just want to be able track the voltages if it is possible using these ICs. This step is a bit beyond me as I'm not familiar with designing using these ICs. I'm still on 78XX & 79XX designs, I could have just used LM317 and 338 designs already out there, however, I am exploring the possibility of using newer ICs as there low noise specs are considerably better.

Comment: @katabatic The model number for the transformer would be nice, if possible. Are you measuring the voltage after the bridge without much of a load on it? Are you looking to do a traditional (old-school) "linear" power supply design?

Comment: Hi, no model no. transformer is ancient! Yes I was measuring AC under no load conditions, the DC was calculated from that. TBH the design is already above I was just wondering how I might implement a way of making it so that the negative rail tracks the positive rail. I have never used these ICs before but as the noise rejection is so low I wondered if it would be considerably better than just using lm78/79xx design, which apparently aren't accurate enough for this job. I am exploring using newer ICs for the job, its got to replace an ancient TA7917P based design..

Comment: @katabatic Given you are making unloaded measurements (and assuming there's a capacitor present) the output will aproach the peaks. If you are seeing about 25V then that's about the peak, so the AC rms would be about 18 -- 0 -- 18 for the secondary. So not too far from what you earlier wrote. Old-school used series inductors to mitigate in-rush, but you also pay a voltage overhead for them when they are 'large enough.' But we used them back in the day. Modern ICs can do wonders. But there's more design and more to think about. I don't know which way you want to go.

Comment: @katabatic However, if you are looking for actually getting up to +/- 15 V with tracking at almost half an amp you cannot afford/accept much by way of smoothing inductors. You'd need about 70 mH and you'd pay about 8 V of overhead for the privilege. You can't afford it. So that kind of old-school is out. There are a lot of tracking supplies on the web. Which have you examined and rejected? Which do you find interesting?

Comment: The old schematic is rectifier then 3300uf capacitor and then transistor driven TA7179P setup. The reason for changing existing PSU is TA7179P is unobtainium. Getting a smps to perform at an acceptable level is beyond my knowledge, so I want to make a tracking supply that can meet  load requirements. I have rejected TPS7A30 and some on semi chips. The  ICs in the design above meet  current requirements and are low noise, they are the first I found. Tbf Im going to do some reading and come back with some figures. Lmxx designs are simple this is a bigger undertaking than I anticipated

Answer (score 1):

You might look at the TPS7A39; a dual, 150-mA, Wide VIN Positive and Negative LDO Voltage Regulator from Texas Instruments. I've been looking at this and wondering if I could use it to drive external series-pass devices and just extend the feedback loops to their outputs. I need more than  150mA for my project.
I came here hoping to find information, but I'm happy to share.
Best of luck.

Edit March 2, 2024
Another possibility I came across recently was using the perennial 723. The article I read pointed out that Texas Instruments (who bought out National Semiconductor) still makes the LM723. It is active and is issued in several grades including military and space (hardened). The reason I mention it is that I built a +/- 15V supply in the early 1980s that still works just fine. And I saw an interesting design that forces the negative supply to track the positive rail. This involves referencing the noninverting input to ground, and the inverting input to the center between equal value resistors to the plus and minus rails. The design wasn't for the LM723, but I think it could be adapted. I plan to breadboard it and experiment. Perhaps applying the same principal to the positive regulator would make it track the negative rail. Wish me luck.

Answer (score 0):

Consider reconsidering your reasoning regarding using "more modern" IC's.  The LM317 has a frighteningly good internal reference.  Using one opamp to derive the negative output from the positive is a very common practice.  Search for dual tracking power supply schematic to see lotsa examples.  The negative output pass device can be an LM337 or a simple power darlington transistor.

Here is a similar thread on another forum:

https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/a-little-help-needed-with-lm741-dual-tracking-power-supply.69531/

Here is an image grab doing exactly what you want:

[image]

Source:  https://www.organised-sound.com/

And another one:

[image]

Source: https://oshwlab.com/Conrad/dual-power-supply